# What is WSO2 identity listener? How it works?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm a newbie in WSO2IS. What is the use of Identity Listener in Identity Management?

From 5.3.0, it seems we have to disable the old identity governance and use the new identity governance features for account locking and disabling. But I can't understand what are they and why this matters.

I did disable the new governance listener and account locking didn't work. As I far I've noticed, when the user is doing incorrect attempts, it is reflected in IDN_IDENTITY_USER_DATA table. On disabling, this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 3):

The idea of user operation event Listeners (org.wso2.carbon.user.core.listener.UserOperationEventListener) is it can be triggered before and after any user store operation such as add user, update password. WSO2 Identity Server utilize such listeners to implement identity management features like account lock.

WSO2 IS 5.3.0 had been released with major revamp to Identity Management feature with the power of new **Identity event frame** work and **Identity Governance framework**. However still you have backward compatibility to use Identity Management feature under old implementation by enabling old IdentityManagementListener (org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.IdentityMgtEventListener) and disabling (org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener)

Recommended way to use account lock in IS 5.3.0 is keep default configuration by enabling (org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener) [1].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Account+Locking+by+Failed+Login+Attempts

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful.

Comment: good one. It helped me in solving one of the issues i was facing